# How do I remove the bottom border from active nav tab?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Here's what I'm getting:
[image: Here's what I'm getting]

Here's my Snippet

```css
.nav-tabs {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #3FA2F7 !important;
}

.nav-tabs .nav-link {
    color: #02194A;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 12.5px !important;
}

.nav-tabs .nav-link.active {
    color: #02194A;
    border-color: #3FA2F7;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #fff !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-tabs-2 justify-content-center d-none d-md-flex">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="curreny-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#curreny" role="tab" aria-controls="curreny" aria-selected="true"><span class="h4 px-4">Curreny Pairs</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="excurreny-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#excurreny" role="tab" aria-controls="excurreny" aria-selected="true"><span class="h4 px-4">Exotic Curreny Pairs</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="indices-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#indices" role="tab" aria-controls="indices" aria-selected="true"><span class="h4 px-4">Indicies</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="metals-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#metals" role="tab" aria-controls="metals" aria-selected="true"><span class="h4 px-4">Metals</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="commodities-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#commodities" role="tab" aria-controls="commodities" aria-selected="true"><span class="h4 px-4">Commodities - Oil</span></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want the bottom border from active nav tab to be removed.

Comment: Please share the HTML, see [mcve]

Comment: Your active nav tab does not _have_ a bottom border to be removed here. This is the border-bottom of the `.nav-tabs` element. You could “hide” that part by _overlaying_ it with a solid color border of the active nav tab (but you would have to move it down by the 3px border width, otherwise it will just sit above that), _if_ you don’t need any transparency/multi-colored backgrounds here. Otherwise, you will have to find a different solution, that does not draw a border in this place to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

This is not `css` border. To remove this you can write this `css`

```css
* {
  outline: none !important;
  box-shadown: none !important'
}
```

This will remove that blue thing around all of your elements. If you don't want to remove it on all the elements just put `class` instead of `*`

I am writing `!important` because you are using bootstrap and you want to override its behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `active` class up to `<li>`, then you can use an absolute positioned pseudo element to hide it like this:

```css
.nav-tabs {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #3FA2F7 !important;
}

.nav-tabs .nav-link {
  color: #02194A;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 12.5px !important;
}

.nav-tabs .nav-link.active {
  color: #02194A;
  border-color: #3FA2F7;
  border-width: 3px;
}

.nav-item {
  position: relative;
}

.nav-item.active::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -2px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #FFF !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-tabs-2 justify-content-center d-none d-md-flex">
  <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" id="curreny-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#curreny" role="tab" aria-controls="curreny" aria-selected="true"><span class="h4 px-4">Curreny Pairs</span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="excurreny-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#excurreny" role="tab" aria-controls="excurreny" aria-selected="true"><span class="h4 px-4">Exotic Curreny Pairs</span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="indices-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#indices" role="tab" aria-controls="indices" aria-selected="true"><span class="h4 px-4">Indicies</span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="metals-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#metals" role="tab" aria-controls="metals" aria-selected="true"><span class="h4 px-4">Metals</span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="commodities-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#commodities" role="tab" aria-controls="commodities" aria-selected="true"><span class="h4 px-4">Commodities - Oil</span></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```